# How can I get the current index of an element with a class? (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my code:

```
$(document).on("change", ".nomeItem", function() {
    if ($(this).val().length) {
        $(this).addClass("input-green");
        $(this).removeClass("input-red");
        $(this).removeClass("input-white");
        if (!($(this).index() in itemNames)) {
            itemNames.add($(this).index());
            itemNames.activate($(this).index());
        } else {
            itemNames.activate($(this).index());
        }
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("input-red");
        $(this).removeClass("input-green");
        $(this).removeClass("input-white");
        showGeneralMessage("É necessário preencher a quantidade!", "danger");
        itemNames.deactivate($(this).index());
    }
    console.log("Nome: " + JSON.stringify(itemNames));
});
```

On the page, there's a button that adds a new "product", and this "product" has this class inside of it (".nomeItem"). `$(this).index()` was supposed to give me the current index (For example, if I trigger a change event inside the third product). Nevertheless, it always returns 1. How can I get the current "eq" or index of an element with a class?

Comment: But your handler is for change event on document object and not on any product

Comment: I must use .on() on the document because new elements with that class are being added (If I use it inside of a .ready() function, it works only for the first one that was loaded together with the page, so I must "listen" to changes on the "future elements").

Comment: So you have `.nomeItem` class name inside multiple element? And they are not inside same container that make their siblings?

Comment: @EricsonWillians Have you tried `event.target.call(this);`?

Comment: It says pretty plainly exactly how to do this in [the docs](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: Two recommendations: 1) Use something like `var $this = $(this)` instead of `$(this)` multiple times. 2) `removeClass` can remove more than one class, and you can chain methods: `$this.addClass('input-green').removeClass('input-red input-white');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use this. This will find the current index from collection of siblings elements:

```
$('.nomeItem').index( $( this ) );
```

Anyway see [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/df1L9qLc/) here. And check the differences between `$('.nomeItem').index( $( this ) );` and  `$( this ).index( );` in action.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this : (assuming your product class is "clsProduct"

```
$(document).on("change", ".clsProduct.nomeItem", function() {
```